# Sort Unicode characters

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting, unicode

Sorting ASCII phrases works fine:

```
Sort[{"albatrob", "abo", "dict", "star", "mangel", "m"}]
(*{"abo", "albatrob", "dict", "m", "mangel", "star"}*)
```

But unless I'm misunderstanding something (which seems likely), sorting Unicode words doesn't work as I'd expect:

```
Sort[{"ɝ", "ʃ", "ɝˈs"}]
(*{"ɝ", "ʃ", "ɝˈs"}*)
```

How does one sort Unicode words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what bases you want to sort Unicode words with but why not try sort based on CharacterCode of first Unicode letter:

```
FromCharacterCode[SortBy[ToCharacterCode[{"ɝ", "ʃ", "ɝˈs"}], First]]

(*{"ɝ", "ɝˈs", "ʃ"}*)
```

Based on your comment this could be one solution:

```
n = Max[Length /@ ToCharacterCode[{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}]];
FromCharacterCode[ Sort[PadRight[#, n] & /@ ToCharacterCode[{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}]]]
(*{"ɝaz","ɝz", "ʃ"}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this only sorts words up to their first letter, and does not sort properly after that. For example, `FromCharacterCode[SortBy[ToCharacterCode[{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}], First]]` gives `{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}`, which is not sorted, since ɝaz alphabetically comes before ɝz.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus, Well, this can be solved :n = Max[Length /@ ToCharacterCode[{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}]];
FromCharacterCode[
 Sort[PadRight[#, n] & /@ ToCharacterCode[{"ɝz", "ɝaz", "ʃ"}]]]

Comment: That seems workable. Thanks and +1! I'll await 24 hours to accept just in case there are other answers.